# Merging several log files in windows, with timestamps

Tags: logging, command-line

I have several log files in windows.  The leading characters of each line are the timestamp and it is always on the same format.  Different modules of the system create individual log files, but as they use the same logging module, they have the same format

Is there any command line utility under windows that would allow me to merge these files, with the interlaced rows?  I want to be able to have a "at a glance" view on the logging.

Comment: On UNIX/CygWin you can simply use `cat file1.log file2.log file3.log | sort -n > file-all.log` - don't know how well it scales

Comment: I am looking for something similar for windows, I wonder if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Try [*Super Speedy Syslog Searcher*](https://crates.io/crates/super_speedy_syslog_searcher). It will process passed log files, then reprint log messages sorting all log messages by the datetime stamp.

(assuming you have [rust installed](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install))

```
cargo install super_speedy_syslog_searcher
```

then

```text
s4.exe C:\path\to\logs
```

or pass the logs directly

```text
s4.exe log1.txt log2.txt
```